# When I use the \d+ TABLE command with PostgreSQL, the output wraps

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface, less-unix

When I try to describe a table in PostgreSQL using `\d+ TABLE` the output wraps. However, I have expanded mode on. I was wondering if someone has a fix for this?

Expected Output: To not wrap around the screen. If possible it should instead look like the expanded view for PostgreSQL tables.

Output now: It will wrap around the screen.

Comment: Can you post what is expected output and the current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use better configuration of pager.

```
PAGER="less -S" psql dbname
```

*Less -S allows lines to be truncated rather than wrapping. You can use side scrolling to see the rest of the lines.*

Or you can install `pspg` - https://github.com/okbob/pspg this is a pager designed specially for database consoles.

```
PAGER=pspg psql dbname
```